# How to curl all files recursively

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, xargs

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
xargs -n 1 curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code} - %{url_effective}\n" < 'file.txt'
```

This works for curling all the URLs that are in `file.txt` and getting the status code and the URL that was curled. However, I need to do this for every file recursively.

I've tried a few things, like this, but none of them worked:

```
xargs -n 1 curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code} - %{url_effective}\n" < *
```

There's about 3000 files in multiple directories.  Is there any way to do this recursively?

Comment: recursively on the server or locally?

Comment: Is wget an option: `wget -r --convert-links -i file_with_urls`? (You may or may not want --convert-links).

Comment: The files are on my server, does it make a difference?

Comment: @Roadowl I'm not seeing any of the content itself, I'm just trying to get the response code of each URL.

Comment: Do you mean when issuing a wget command like above, no download is performed? Do you have a $HOME/.wgetrc file?

Comment: `wget --mirror` reads everything recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that your file list's name has a rule like this: file.txt, file1.txt, file2.txt under the current working directory including the subdirectories.

You could merge all the links in those files with `cat **/file*.txt` command, then combine it with the `xargs`:

```sh
cat **/file*.txt | xargs -n 1 curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code} - %{url_effective}\n"
```

Good luck!

Comment: i would use `< find . -iname "*.txt"` instead

Comment: @hanshenrik `<` accepts a file list as stdin but an expression, it should be `< $(find . -iname "*.txt")`, also, correct my `cat` expression, too.